# Rename part of the directory names?

Tags: python, bash

The following command found the following directories.

```
$ find tmp/ -name "date=*" -type d
tmp/year=2022/month=05/date=27
tmp/year=2022/month=05/date=21
tmp/year=2022/month=05/date=29
tmp/year=2022/month=05/date=24
tmp/year=2022/month=05/date=31
tmp/year=2022/month=06/date=01
tmp/year=2022/month=06/date=02
```

I need to rename the directories by replacing `date=` to `day=`.

```
find tmp/ -name "date=*" -type d -exec rename s/date=/day=/g "{}" +;
```

However, the command doesn't rename the directories?

I will need to implement it in Python.

Comment: I'm curious: why not just use a structure like `tmp/2022/06/02`, for example?

Comment: `rename` is not a standard command; there are several contenders. If you have an error in how you invoke this command, we can't diagnose that without knowing which version you have. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Something like this will do it: `find tmp/ -name "date=*" -type d -exec rename 'date=' 'day='  "{}" +;`.

Comment: A somewhat more portable equivalent would be `... -exec bash -c 'for f; do mv "$f" "${f//date=/day=}"; done' _ {} +` though this still depends on Bash which of course is reasonably ubiquitous but not standard. (The double `//` matches your `/g` flag which however seems superfluous for these examples; it says to replace all matches if there are several occurrences within a single file name.)

Comment: @accdias You seem to be assuming they simply have a different version of `rename` which seems ... out on a limb.

Comment: @accdias the command works (`'data=' 'day='`). However, it doesn't work after I ran it using Python `subprocess.run(['find', 'tmp/', '-name', '"date=*"', '-type', 'd', '-exec', 'rename', 'date=', 'day=', '"{}"', '+;'])`?

Comment: @triplee, indeed. I'm just constructing above what op already posted. Your solution is clearly better and more portable.

Comment: @ca9163d9, so you shouldn't have omitted  that part from us. You have a lot better option in Python using `pathlib` and no shell invoking at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Python 3.4+, you can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```py
from pathlib import Path

tmp = Path('tmp')

for o in tmp.rglob('date=*'):
    if o.is_dir():
        o.rename(o.with_name(o.name.replace('date', 'day')))
```

To address the problem you mentioned in your post comment, you can check if the target directory already exists and then workaround it the way you want. Something like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

tmp = Path('tmp')

for o in tmp.rglob('date=*'):
    new_name = o.with_name(o.name.replace('date', 'day'))
    if o.is_dir():
        if new_name.exists():
            # Your logic to work around a directory
            # that already exists goes here
        else:
            o.rename(new_name)
```

The code above is just an initial idea. It needs a lot of improvement to be made more reliable.

Comment: Sometime, e.g., both `date=01\aaa.zip` and `day=01/bbb.zip` exist. And the code will got error of `FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'tmp/year=2022/month=05/date=01' -> 'tmp/year=2022/month=05/day=01'`. Is it a way to skip renaming and move the files if the target directory name already exists?

Comment: Sure! You can check if the target name already exists. I will try to update the code with that test.

Answer (score 4):

`rename` utility is not part of standard Unix tool/utilities and comes in different flavors.

I may suggest sticking with `bash` and `mv` using this `find` command:

```bash
find tmp -name "date=*" -type d -exec bash -c '
   for f;do echo mv "$f" "${f/date=/day=}"; done' _ {} +
```

I have kept `echo` before `mv` for your testing purpose. Once satisfied with the output just remove `echo` from above command.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this from Python anyway, a subprocess is just unnecessary.

```
import os

for curdir, dirs, files in os.walk("/tmp"):
    for dirname in dirs:
        if dirname.startswith("date="):
            new = dirname.replace("date=", "day=")
            os.rename(os.path.join(curdir, dirname), os.path.join(curdir, new))
```